# Почему цикл анимации в OpenGL выполняется с разной скоростью на разных ПК?

Tags: c++, opengl

Я запустил простой код с использованием OpenGL...  на 2х компьютерах. Там простое перемещение квадрата. Но на одном компьютере квадрат перемещается быстрее.. чем на другом. Почему так? Это ли не есть ФПС? Может анимацию надо как то залочить? Что бы везде было одинаково.

Comment: залог плавной анимации - зависимость от delta time, покажите Ваш код.

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать счетчик FPS и показывайте его в заголовке окна или рисуйте где нибудь в левом/правом верхнем углу экрана. Потом рендер экрана должен происходить не в рандомный момент времени. Каждая итерация рендера занимает разное время. Попробуйте рендерить каждый 1000 тик, то есть стараться запускать каждую итерацию рендера с таким промежутком, чтобы начало рендера было кратно 1000 тику.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Это ли не есть ФПС?

да, это именно тот самый fps - кол-во отрисованных кадров в секунду
и оно может быть разным в зависимости от вычислительных мощностей

> Может анимацию надо как то залочить?

да, так обычно и делается

грубо говоря вы хотите рисовать со скоростью 50fps (50 кадров в секунду), т.е. 1 кадр отрисовывать за 0,02 сек, хотя ваши вычислительные мощности позволяют вам отрисовывать 1 кадр за 0.01 сек (т.е. 100fps)

вы делаете такую вещь:

1. засекаете время перед отрисовкой кадра
2. засекаете время после отрисовки кадра
3. если у вас получилось меньше 0,02 сек (скажем 0,015 сек), то вы ждёте до тех пор пока не пройдет оставшееся до 0,02 сек время (скажем, 0,005 сек), после чего отрисовываете следующий кадр
4. если у вас получилось больше, чем 0,02 сек, то вы не ждете совсем для отрисовки следующего кадра

в результате все быстрые вычислительные мощности будут отрисовывать анимацию с 50fps, а все что медленнее с тем fps, который у них получается

т.е. получается такой алгоритм:

```
const float c_fps = 60; // хотим рисовать с частотой 60fps

while (true) {
    // определяем время начала отрисовки
    const time_t timer_start = getTime();

    // отрисовываем сцену
    render();

    // определяем время завершения отрисовки
    const time_t timer_finish = getTime();

    // определяем длительность отрисовки сцены и время до следующей отрисовки
    const time_t timer_delta = 1 / c_fps - (timer_finish - timer_start);

    // если время до следующей отрисовки положительно (т.е. сцена отрисована быстрее, чем c_fps) - ждем
    if (timer_delta > 0) {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(timer_delta);
    }
}
```

код я привел в псеводокоде, т.е. таких типов и функций не существует (кроме `WaitForSingleObject`) и их надо заменить своими

**НО НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ ДЕЛАЕТСЯ ЧАЩЕ ВСЕГО ПО ДРУГОМУ!**

1. отрисовка сцены происходит постоянно без задержек в отдельном потоке
2. но перемещение объектов в сцене завязано не на фиксированное перемещение за каждый кадр, а на фиксированное перемещение за единицу времени

например человек идет по улице со скоростью 5км/ч и снимаете вы его на видео с 25fps или 120fps идти он будет на первом и втором видео с одинаковой скоростью, просто на первом видео он за 1 кадр пройдет 1 метр, а во втором видео - 20см

```
const float speed = 10.5; // скорость перемещения 10.5 пикселей в секунду

// определяем время начала анимации
const time_t timer_start = getTime();

while(true) {
    // определяем текущее время
    const time_t timer_current = getTime();

    // вычислить текущую позицию объекта
    const float pos = pos_start + (time_current - time_start) * speed;

    // отрисовываем сцену
    render(pos);
}
```

**НО ЕЩЕ ПРАВЕЕ**

совмещают оба подхода, ну просто потому что рисовать что-то с 1000fps не нужно :) по идее вот сколько монитор дает fps с таким fps максимум и можно рисовать

Comment: Иногда используется и подход обсчета по таймеру, когда  отрисовка завязываетя на фиксированный цикл обсчета физических процессов (в отдельном потоке) или обмена по сети, зачастую с обратными связями для компенсации нерегулярностей